# SAAS Project Management Methodology with API driven and User Centered Design focuses

Tags: project-management-style, methodology, user-experience-design

How can API driven project management methodolgy for SAAS applications can involve user centered design? I mean in which state User Scenarios, Personas (thus focusing on the UX) can be involved?

Answer (score 1):

In traditional project management, most UX activities occur during the early (Software Development Life Cycle (SDLC) phases.  Personas and scenarios would be created as requirements are gathered and analyzed.  Application flow and style guides would be created during the design phase.

In modern *product* management, the user is an active participant throughout the process, providing feedback on each increment if the effort as it is being created or modified.  The UX designer would be involved in facilitating those conversations.